# Appending a select drop down with jQuery and setting it's value

Tags: jquery, select, append

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <head>
        <title>TimeSheet Edit Page</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="jqueryui/css/redmond/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.min.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="jqGrid/css/ui.jqgrid.css" />
        <script src="jquery/jquery-2.0.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="jqueryui/js/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="jqGrid/js/i18n/grid.locale-en.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="jqGrid/js/minified/jquery.jqGrid.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            jTimesheetid = "";
            jTimesheetweekending = "";
            jJobsSelect = "";
            $(document).ready(function() {

                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "php.scripts/timesheet.getsession.php",
                    data: {},
                    async: false
                }).done(function(msg) {
                    obj = JSON.parse(msg);
                    jTimesheetid = obj.timesheetid;
                    jTimesheetweekending = obj.timesheetweekending;
                });

                jQuery('#h3Timesheetid').text("Time Sheet ID: " + jTimesheetid);
                jQuery('#h3Timesheetweekending').text("Time Sheet Week Ending: " + jTimesheetweekending);

                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "php.scripts/buildselect.jobs.php",
                    data: {},
                    async: false
                }).done(function(msg) {
                    jJobsSelect = msg;
                });


                //Check the database for any tablets.(AJAX)
                //On return from AJAX
                //If there are no tablets display a message that there are no tablets to display
                //If there are tabblets in the database display each tablet

                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "php.scripts/tablet.getdata.php",
                    data: {},
                    async: false
                }).done(function(tablets) {
                    obj = JSON.parse(tablets);
                    if (obj == "") {
                        jQuery("#pMsg").html('No rows to display.');
                    } else {
                        for (var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
                            console.log(obj[i].JobNo);

                            //for each tablet in the database display the tablet in the client area
                            $("body").append("<div id=\"tablet" + obj[i].idtablets + "\" style=\"margin: 5px 0px 0px 0px; width: 1102px; border: 1px solid grey; height: 200px;\"></div>");
                            $("#tablet" + obj[i].idtablets).append("<div id=\"leftcolumn" + obj[i].idtablets + "\" style=\"width: 200px; float: left; height: 200px;\"></div>");
                            $("#leftcolumn" + obj[i].idtablets).append("<div style=\"width: 196px; border: 1px solid red; height: 48px;\"><p>JobNo</p></div>");
                            $("#leftcolumn" + obj[i].idtablets).append("<div style=\"width: 196px; border: 1px solid red; height: 48px;\">" + jJobsSelect.toString() + "</div>");
                        }
                    }
                });

                $("body").append("<input type=\"button\" id=\"tabletadd\" value=\"tablet.add\" />");
            });
        </script>
        <script type="text/javascript">

        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
         <h3 id="h3Timesheetid">Time Sheet ID:</h3>

         <h3 id="h3Timesheetweekending">Time Sheet Week Ending Day:</h3>

        <p id="pMsg"></p>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $("#tabletadd").click(function() {
                alert("Handler for .click() called.");
            });
        </script>
    </body>

</html>
```

In this case `jJobsSelect` contains some text that makes up the select drop down:

```
<select><option value="328">328</option><option value="329">329</option></select>
```

The select statement drop down does appear in my HTML as it is supposed to however I need to also set it's currently selected value equal to the value of `obj[i].JobNo`. Is there some way to set the currently selected value of the select equal to `obj[i].JobNo` after it is appended? I am also looking for a way to attach an `onChange` event to each select drop down after it is appended as well.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: I don't see where the `select` gets appended? Am I missing it?

Comment: jJobsSelect represents the selects HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the

```
$("#leftcolumn" + obj[i].idtablets).append("<div style=\"width: 196px; border: 1px solid red; height: 48px;\">" + jJobsSelect.toString() + "</div>");
```

add a

```
var selectElement = $("#leftcolumn" + obj[i].idtablets).find('select');
selectElement.find('options').filter(function(){
   return this.value.toLowerCase() === obj[i].JobNo.toString().toLowerCase();
}).prop('selected', true);

selectElement.on('change', function(){
   // handle change event here..
});
```

Comment: The change event is working fine but the code to change the selected value isn't yet I will have to start troubleshooting. Thanks for the code.

Comment: This was the code that did it for me. jQuery 2.0.0. selectElement.val(obj[i].JobNo.toString().toLowerCase());